# RubyMine Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, rubymine

When I'm trying to run debugger on Rails application (2.1.3) in Ruby Mine I get the following error:

```
> /home/vladimirn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby /home/vladimirn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide --disable-int-handler --port 38013 --dispatcher-port 33518 -- /home/vladimirn/Dev/Projects/untitled/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development
/home/vladimirn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- debase_internals (LoadError)
    from /home/vladimirn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/vladimirn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/debase-0.0.9/lib/debase.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vladimirn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/vladimirn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/vladimirn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vladimirn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `require_relative'
    from /home/vladimirn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.23.beta1/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `<main>'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

It looks like the problem is with debase gem.
When I'm trying to remove it and reinstall with RubyMine i get the following:

```
> error running Development: untitled: Failed to Install Gems. Following gems were not installed: /home/vladimirn/Dev/RubyMine-6.3.3/rb/gems/debase-0.0.9.gem: Error installing debase-0.0.9.gem: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. /home/vladimirn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141004-13252-i5wsfb.rb extconf.rb checking for vm_core.h... no checking for vm_core.h... no Makefile creation failed ************************************************************************** No source for ruby-2.1.3-p242 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem. ************************************************************************** *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options. Provided configuration options: --with-opt-dir --without-opt-dir --with-opt-include --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include --with-opt-lib --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib --with-make-prog --without-make-prog --srcdir=. --curdir --ruby=/home/vladimirn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby --with-ruby-dir --without-ruby-dir --with-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include --with-ruby-lib --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/lib extconf failed, exit code 1 Gem files will remain installed in /home/vladimirn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/debase-0.0.9 for inspection. Results logged to /home/vladimirn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/debase-0.0.9/gem_make.out
```

This looks like there is a problem with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.

I run it manually from terminal:

```
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source
```

But if i run afterward gem install debase once again I will get the same error.

Any ideas how i can configure Debugger with RubyMine running on Ubuntu 14?

Comment: Hey mate, did you figure this out for use with debase?

Comment: no not yet. still getting errors. I've tried pry, but it doesn't work with RubyMine

Comment: Ok i'll have a play with this in the morning and let you know.  This has my work machine up the creek since updating to rails 4

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by rolling back to ruby 2.1.2 with rails 4.1.6.   Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it works now since new version release of debase. So working with ruby 2.1.3 now and RubyMine :)

Comment: Awesome news, looks like I'll try come forward to 2.1.3 then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `debase 0.1.0` which [includes the latest ruby sources](https://github.com/denofevil/debase/compare/v0.0.9...v0.1.0) hadn't been released.

But [it has just been released 20 minutes ago](https://github.com/denofevil/debase/releases/tag/v0.1.0), so if you reinstall Rubymine or the `debase` gem now, it should work.

Comment: @VladimirNovick: You could consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this as the correct answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

Ran into the same problem trying to get the debugger to work with Rubymine for 2.1.4 - I used the specific_install gem to install the latest debase from github which totally fixed it --

```
bundle exec gem install specific_install
gem specific_install https://github.com/denofevil/debase.git
```

Answer (score 2):

The debugger gem isn't supposed to be used with ruby 2.0+, and literally won't install with ruby 2.1.2(+). You are going to have to switch to byebug.

If you're a fan of pry there is also pry-byebug

Here is how my debugging gems in my Gemfile look like with Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.2

```
group :development do
    gem 'pry'
    gem 'pry-remote'
    gem 'pry-rails'
    gem 'pry-stack_explorer'
    gem 'pry-byebug'
end
```

Comment: The problem is that RubyMine as far as i know does not support pry yet. by Default if you create new Rails application with Ruby 2.1.2 or 2.1.3 and runs it in Debug mode it asks you if you want to install debase gem which has a lot of dependencies on debugger.